# Cross browser Testing

Tags: css, user-interface, browser, cross-browser

Due to Bootstrap upgrade, there has been lots of changes in the CSS in all pages of the web application that I'm working on. This application is also mobile optimized. So I have the task the checking the UI of all pages of our application accross most browsers - IE8,9,10,11 , chrome, firefox, ios and android devices(phone, 7 inch, 10 inch).

Right now, I'm opening the existing version(old bootstrap) and the updated version(New bootstrap) of my website in 2 tabs, and switch back and forth between them to find out any UI issues like alignment and color change and text size.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are somewhat solutions to it, which make cross-browser and multiple device testing easy. Some of them are:

Ghostlab: allows synchronized testing which means if you click or scroll in one browser it happens across all browsers. It has many other features but is only for Mac.

Grunt also allows for synchronized testing. Check [this article](http://mattbailey.io/grunt-synchronised-testing-between-browsers-devices/)

you can do cross browser testing within a browser using online services such as

Last thing I would mention is xip.io just check it out!!!

Chrome DevTools are awesome for this purpose. They allow you to override settings for different devices by **Developer Tool>Settings>Overrides** you can override following to emulate

- User agents
- Device metrics
- Device orientation
- Touch events
- CSS media